# Get URL(link) of a public S3 object programmatically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am storing one public object in AWS S3 bucket using given java API in my server
Now i need to return back the public URL of the S3 object to my client

Till now i have'nt found any API call that can return the public URL(or link field) of a S3 object

Is there any way to get the URL??

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**For Java SDK 2**

```
s3Client.utilities().getUrl(builder -> builder.bucket(AWS_BUCKET).key(s3RelativeFilePath)).toExternalForm();
```

Reference - https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Utilities.html#getUrl-java.util.function.Consumer-

**older versions had:**

```
s3Client.getResourceUrl(bucket, s3RelativeToBucketPath);
```

Comment: It seems it should be AmazonS3.getUrl(bucket, path)

Comment: You cannot use these URLs to use sometime later, since these URLs has a expiration time.

Comment: How do you create the s3Client?, what is builder? what should contain s3RelativeFilePath?

Answer (score 9):

For SDK-2 version, Kotlin:

```
s3.utilities().getUrl { it.bucket("BUCKET").key("FILEPATH") }.toExternalForm()
```

Answer (score 8):

i am using **`aws-java-sdk-s3 1.11.58`**

accepted answer not working on this version.

below line works for this version

```
s3Client.getUrl(AWS_BUCKET, s3RelativeFilePath).toExternalForm();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
"https://"+{bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com+"/"+key
```

This URL may look different from the link in object overview in S3. But it works just as the same. 
Note: The link in object overview usually looks like

```
  https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/{bucket}/{key}
```

Answer (score 2):

**For users, who have private buckets and requires the URL.**

In my case, I had to get downloadable link of S3 Object for a specific time as my bucket is **private**.

I'm using Spring Cloud AWS, which under the hood uses AWS SDK For Java and which provides **AmazonS3** interface for interacting with S3, use **AmazonS3Client** if you're using AWS SDK For JAVA instead of **AmazonS3**. I simply injected **AmazonS3** and now I can get URL of an object where-ever required, but it can be downloaded within 5 mins else it will be expired.

```
 public String getURL(String key) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    try {
        return amazonS3.generatePresignedUrl(BUCKET_NAME, key, new DateTime().plusMinutes(5).toDate()).toString();
    }
    catch (AmazonS3Exception exception){
        if(exception.getStatusCode() == 404){
            throw new FileNotFoundException(key);
        }
        else{
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Kotlin sdk `implementation("aws.sdk.kotlin:s3:1.0.58")`

here, how I am generating url from aws s3 bucket.

```
fun generatePublicUrl(region: String, bucketName: String, objectKey: String): String {
    val endpoint = "https://$bucketName.s3.$region.amazonaws.com/$objectKey"
    return URL(endpoint).toString()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider constructing the url using bucket name and object key instead of making a request to s3 everytime to just fetch the url.

Comment: According to the documentation for S3Utilities as of version 2.17.197 "Note: This class does not make network calls." https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Utilities.html

Answer (score -5):

"https://s3.amazonaws.com/"+bucketName+"/"+key should give you the url to the object in s3

Comment: the url that is produced is "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/se252j14-cloud9/1391200395934.html" . Now how can i get the s3 end point

Comment: But that is the s3 end point URL, not sure i understand your question about the end point.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the selected answer doesn't seem to exist any more in the API.

Comment: The getResourceUrl still exists in the API (1.11.28), see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getResourceUrl-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-