# S3 generate download link

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm having trouble generating a download link for an html file i'm uploading to aws s3 server. I am able to generate the link and access the file. But what I want to happen is that when I click the link is for the file to be downloaded instead of opening it.

Here is and example of the url:

```
https://wassap_app.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/report/test.html
```

Below is the code for the method that does the upload:

```
public boolean uploadFile(String name) {
    try {
        this.client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, "report/" + name, this.file)
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
        String url = client.getUrl(bucketName, "report/" + name).toExternalForm();
        System.out.println("################ Download File URL ################");
        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println("###################################################");
        return true;
    } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
        return false;
    } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I should have posted that answer here, but it appeared after I answered on that post. So refer to this thread [Downloadable Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55728583/6332074), where brief explanation is given.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `response-content-disposition` query parameter as [documented here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html#RESTObjectGET-requests). Your URL will then look like:

```
https://wassap_app.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/report/test.html?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22report.html%22
```

But the documentation also states:

> You must sign the request, either using an Authorization header or a
>   pre-signed URL, when using these parameters. They cannot be used with
>   an unsigned (anonymous) request.

To sign the request for the user you can use a presigned URL. I don't have a Java environment to test right now, but something like the following should work.

```
GeneratePresignedUrlRequest req = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, "report/" + name);
ResponseHeaderOverrides overrides = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
overrides.setContentDisposition("attachment; filename=\"report.html\"");
req.setResponseHeaders(overrides);
URL url = this.client.generatePresignedUrl(req);
System.out.println(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Call this method:**

```
String url = client.getResourceUrl(bucketName, "report/" + name);
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: Hi, Eleazar getResourceUrl doesn't exist, im using version 1.11.235