# c# .netcore Get ImageURL of all files under amazon s3 folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

Using C# and amazon .Net core, able to list all the files URL path with in a amazon S3 folder as below:

```
       public async Task<string> GetMenuUrl(entities.Restaurant restaurant)
        {
            AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(_appSettings.AWSPublicKey, _appSettings.AWSPrivateKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);

            string imagePath;
            int restaurantId = restaurant.RestaurantId;
            ListObjectsRequest listRequest = new ListObjectsRequest();
            ListObjectsResponse listResponse; 

            imagePath = $"Business_menu/{restaurantId}/";
            listRequest.BucketName = _appSettings.AWSS3BucketName;
            listRequest.Prefix = imagePath;

            do
            {

                listResponse = await s3Client.ListObjectsAsync(listRequest);

            } while (listResponse.IsTruncated);


            var files = listResponse.S3Objects.Select(x => x.Key);
            
            var fileName = files.Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList(); //outputs Test.jpg, Test2.jpg on this line

            var fileNameJoin = string.Join(", ", fileName); 

            var result = fileNameJoin.Split(); // contains 2 files Test.jpg, Test2.jpg

            //Need AWSS3BucketUrl for all files in imagePath 
            string imageUrl = $"{_appSettings.AWSS3BucketUrl}{imagePath}{result}";

            
            return imageUrl;
        }

 public async Task<MenuResponse> GetVenueMenuUrl(int restaurantId)
        {


            var restaurant = await _context.Restaurant.Where(w => w.RestaurantId == restaurantId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            var result = await _Service.GetMenuUrl(restaurant);

            
            var response = new MenuResponse()
            {
                MenuUrl = result
            };

            return response;
        }
```

I want to return each imageurl as the following:

```
 {
      menuUrl : "https://...bucketpath../test.jpg"
 },
 {
      menuUrl: "https://...bucketpath../test2.jpg"
 },
```

What Is currently being outputted:

```
{
    "menuUrl": "https://..bucketpath../System.String[]"
}
```

It should be outputting two imageUrls not one and also it seems to be outputting the list type not the content.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TListObjectsResponse.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487066/get-urllink-of-a-public-s3-object-programmatically

Comment: Im already using listobjectresponse

Comment: You are only using `listobjectresponse` but not any of it's properties. If you read the documentation carefully you will notice that it has a property called `S3Objects` which is a collection of all the S3 objects returned in the response. You need to loop thru that collection to get the more details about each of them. You can use Key property of S3Object and the other link I share to create url of the image.

Comment: using it here             var files = listResponse.S3Objects.Select(x => x.Key);

Comment: think I might need a foreach statement to output all the imageURLs or something

Comment: files in your code will be collection of strings then you are creating another collection from it called fileName. Then you are creating a single string out of it by  doing string.join. You need to take a step back and debug your code carefully and understand what's happening there. And apply appropriate solution there.

Comment: don't quite understand how to output them separately as shown in my expected response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string imageUrl = $"{_appSettings.AWSS3BucketUrl}{imagePath}{result}";
```

You're telling C# to concatenate a string with "result", but "result" is not a string, it's an array. To tell the compiler what you really want, you need to get the individual strings out of the array and use those instead.

It also looks like you're converting your result into JSON in code we can't see. If that's the case, you could try returning a list of objects from your function instead of a string, which will then get serialized into something a lot closer to your expected output:

```
// make a simple class that will be serialized cleanly
public class MenuURL
{
    public string menuUrl;
}

// .... back in your function ....

List<MenuURL> URLs = new List<MenuURL>();

// Loop through your "results" variable
foreach (string str in result)
{
    MenuURL url = new MenuURL()
    {
        menuUrl = $"{_appSettings.AWSS3BucketUrl}{imagePath}{str}"
    };

    URLs.Add(url);
}

return URLs;
```

When you convert the list you get back into JSON, it should look more like what you want, ie:

```
 [
     {
          "menuUrl" : "https://...bucketpath../test.jpg"
     },
     {
          "menuUrl": "https://...bucketpath../test2.jpg"
     },
 ]
```