# Upload multiple files to an S3 bucket and return their URL paths and names

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm using below code to upload a file to an S3 bucket, but I want to get the `objectUrl` in the response, which has the S3 URL for the file. How can I do it?

```
try {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(region)
        .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
        .build();
    TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
        .withS3Client(s3Client)
        .build();

    // TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously,
    // so this call returns immediately.
    Upload upload = tm.upload(mediaBucket, keyName, new File(filePath));
    System.out.println("Object upload started");

    // Optionally, wait for the upload to finish before continuing.
    upload.waitForCompletion();
    System.out.println("Object upload complete");
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (SdkClientException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no way to do this in a single operation, you need to upload the file then fetch the URL separately.

The latest API has a [waitForUploadResult()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Upload.html#waitForUploadResult--) method in the [Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/Upload.html) interface. That returns an [UploadResult](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/model/UploadResult.html) object which has the [getBucketName()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/model/UploadResult.html#getBucketName--) and [getKey()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/model/UploadResult.html#getKey--) methods, you can then use those to get the URL using the [AmazonS3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html) class that has a [getUrl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#getUrl-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method.

```java
try {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(region)
        .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
        .build();
    TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
        .withS3Client(s3Client)
        .build();

    Upload upload = tm.upload(mediaBucket, keyName, new File(filePath));
    UploadResult uploadResult = upload.waitForUploadResult();
    
    URL fileUrl = s3Client
        .getUrl(
            uploadResult.getBucketName(),
            uploadResult.getKey()
         );
    
    // do something with URL

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I got this information from looking at the documentation and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487066/get-urllink-of-a-public-s3-object-programmatically).

Comment: I dont see utilities() method for AmazonS3 class.

Comment: @Teletubbies I updated the answer to reflect the latest API